# Failed to find app bundle in zip file

Tags: ios, iphone, appstore-approval

Recently,I have upload an iPhone app to apple store.When I finished uploading.I received a email from apple. Warn me that the binary is invalid due to "Failed to find app bundle in zip file". Try upload several times, but still the same problem. I wonder If any one have this problem?And how to solve this problem.Thanks.

The email is here:

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "XXXX app(With Chinese)". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:
>
> Failed to find app bundle in zip file - The zip file you submit must contain exactly one .app bundle, and the .app bundle must reside at the top level of the zip file, not nested in a subdirectory. The best way to accomplish this is to create the zip file by selecting your .app bundle (e.g., MyCoolApp.app) in the Finder and choosing "Compress MyCoolApp.app" from the File menu.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, go to the Version Details page and click "Ready to Upload Binary." Continue through the submission process until the app status is "Waiting for Upload." You can then deliver the corrected binary.

Comment: Check the budle id in the provisioning profile and app bundle id are same

Answer (score 0):

You need to check bundle in Provisioning Profile as well as in app bundle id.Both are must be same.

Please check it, it is correct or not.

After that You are able to upload your binary on App Store.

Good Luck !!!!